# PHP file_get_contents not working

Tags: php

i am having a problem with PHP file_get_contents.

```
$html = file_get_html($csfd_link);
```

Writes an error:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known in /home/vo003500/www_root/admin/simple_html_dom.php on line 76
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known in /home/vo003500/www_root/admin/simple_html_dom.php on line 76

I do not know what it is. The server is **`allow_url_fopen ON`**

Thanks

Edit:
Until now it worked, but the last 2 weeks not working...

Comment: It means it cannot translate a DNS name into an IP....

Comment: What is in the variable `$csfd_link`? You'll probably find it's not a valid file name or URL.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your suffering from DNS (Domain Name Service) resolution error. Make sure there is a proper DNS server entry in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment since it's just suggestion not solution.